# Run command on last item in each() in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, each

I have an array of 'tasks' that I am getting back from a JSON response that I am iterating through, and doing some processing on each task.  Here is some psudocode:

```
def tasks = grails.converters.JSON.parse(json response)
tasks.each() {task ->
  //do some processing here
}
```

On the very last task in the list, I want to run an additional operation.  I'm looking for a built in way to do this in grails/groovy.  My searches have thus far yielded no results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another possible solution is

```
tasks.eachWithIndex() { task, i ->
//whatever
   if(i == tasks.size() - 1){
      //something else
   }
}
```

Comment: should be `size()` - using `size` only works in the Sun JDKs since it accesses a private field

Answer (score 1):

Another method might be to do something along the lines of:

```
tasks[0..-1].each {
  // Processing for all but last element
}
tasks[-1   ].each {
  // Processing for last element
}
```

Of course, if there's only one element in the `tasks` list, then it will get both processing applied to it (and if there are no elements in the list, it will crash) :-/

---

**edit**

An alternative (which may not be considered as easily readable), is as follows:

```
// A list of 'tasks' in our case Strings
tasks = [
  'a', 'b', 'c'
]

// Create a list of Closures the length of our list of tasks - 1
processing = (1..<tasks.size()).collect { { task -> "Start $task" } }
// Append a Closure to perform on the last item in the list
processing << { task -> "Final $task" }

// Then, transpose these lists together, and execute the Closure against the task
def output = [tasks,processing].transpose().collect { task, func -> func( task ) }
```

After running this, `output` is equal to:

```
[Start a, Start b, Final c]
```

And this works with task lists with just one item

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is along the lines of:

```
tasks.each() {task ->
  //do some processing here
}
tasks[-1].doSomethingElse()
```

(provided tasks.size() > 0).

The [-1] syntax means last in the list.

Comment: I need to avoid running the operation twice though... I could just get a count of the number of tasks and iterate through all but one, but I'm looking for a cleaner, built in function to do so.

Comment: On the very last task do you want to run an operation _in addition_ to the normal one, or _instead_ of it? I read your question to mean _in addition_.